# How do I set up clangd for Netbeans 12.1

Tags: c++, clangd

How do I set up clangd for netbeans 12.1 because I cannot find anything online about setup with netbeans

Comment: Are you sure netbeans supports clangd?

Comment: it should, it has an option for it, but i have no idea how to set it up

Comment: I'm not seeing Netbeans in the list of editors that support the language server protocol: https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/implementors/tools/